# SchemaVersion Not Declared When Installing Facebook 5.0.9.0

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

When I try to install Facebook 5.0.9.0 from the Library Package Manager (or the Package Manager Console), I get an error that states "The 'schemaVersion' attribute is not declared".  I did not have this problem with 5.0.8.0, so just wondering if something has changed or I'm not installing this version correctly.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem installed the latest nuget from http://nuget.org/
It is solved now